# Is there any way to identify the user across browser using javascript navigator information?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to identify user across browser if the user is on same machine and allow him/her to login seamlessly. is there any information that i can use to trace the user?

Comment: user in the sense what, machine?

Comment: yes , actually not user but user's machine or device ?